# Ajax on Success redirect URL from controller

Tags: php, ajax, model-view-controller, zend-framework

Current Page is Add.phtml..when click saves button, it should be redirected to index.phtml..the URL for index page already inside a controller.
but I can't make it..can anyone point me which part is wrong?

JS inside add.phtml

```
function addMembAndAppDetail(){
        var m_register = 0;
        if($('input[name="register"]').is(':checked'))
        {
             m_register = 1;
        }
        var m_active = 0;
        if($('input[name="status"]').is(':checked'))
        {
            m_active = 1;
        }

        $.ajax({
            url: '/membership/membership-setup/ajax-add-multiple/',
            type: 'POST',
            async : false,
            data: {
                        'm_owner' : $('#m_owner').val(),

            },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(response){
                 window.location.href = response.url;
            }
        });
    }
```

Inside Controller

```
    public function ajaxAddMultipleAction(){

        $auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();
        $data = array(
            'm_owner' => $this->_getParam('m_owner', null)
        );

        $membershipDb = new Membership_Model_DbTable_TblMembership();
        $membershipDb->addData($data);

        $this->_helper->flashMessenger->addMessage(array('success' => "Record saved"));
        $url = $this->_redirect($this->baseUrl . '/membership/membership-setup/index');


        echo json_encode(array('msg'=>"Success.", 'url'=>$url, 'status'=>true));
    }
```

Comment: I don't see you making any (or attempting to make any) redirect anywhere. All I can see is that you return a json object with a URL but I don't see you using it anywhere other than in an alert? Also, why do you have `async: false`?

Answer (score 0):

You just returning the url but you never used it. if your url is valid then you can change your success method to redirect the client

```
success: function(response){
    window.location.href = response.url
}
```

**Edit**
I tested out your ajax call and it looks like that if you remove `dataType: 'json'` it works perfectly. I don't know why it cause the issue but after removing it it should work.
anyways `dataType` default value is `Intelligent Guess` so it will guess the data type automatically for you